# "ScriptResource.axd" vulnerability in Windows Server 2008

Tags: webserver, sql-injection, sql-server

I am using Windows Server 2008, Plesk 9.5, IIS 7, SQL Server 2008, and recently I have received and email claiming this server is vulnerable, and sent me the following URL:

`/scriptresource.axd?d=QivxuR3S70uO2-sZID2TL45AtoGwC4WTODQ6W4h3ca0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0`

Using this URL on any website that I hosted on the server, I could see the `web.config` file. I would like to know whether this indeed is a vulnerability, and if so, how to mitigate it?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like that's the padding oracle attack that came out in 2010.  You should check your server for the appropriate MS patch ([MS10-070](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-070)).

There's more information on the attack [here](http://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2010/9/14/automated-padding-oracle-attacks-with-padbuster.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer,i did solve the problem by installing latest patches of dot-net fretwork that released by Microsoft

Comment: @jackBauer - Sounds like you ought to accept Rory's answer then, since it solved the problem presented in your question. ;)